# Replacing Absolute file path by Resource file path

Tags: vb.net, resources

I created an add-in to an existing software (Revit) and I want to embed an image (my company's logo) in the add-in's button.

Here is my current code for it:

```
'Set the large image shown on button
        Dim uriImage As New Uri("\\10.8.60.3\Shared\REVIT\FSElogo.png")
        Dim largeImage As New BitmapImage(uriImage)
        MainButton.LargeImage = largeImage
```

It works pretty well and the logo is correctly displayed, however it requires the computer to have access to the server located at `\\10.8.60.3`. When working from home, we do not have access to this server and Revit throws an error when starting because of it.

So I tried adding the `FSElogo.png` file to my VB.Net project as a `Resource` and then tried to use `My.Resources` to access the image, effectively removing the need for an external image to be used.

Well, I can't get it to work.
I tried replacing the code above by

`MainButton.LargeImage = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("FSElogo.png"), Windows.Media.ImageSource)`

But it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error, but no image is displayed on the button.

If I don't cast my `Object` to an `ImageSource` I get an `implicit conversion from Object to Image` error, and I'm not even sure my `ResourceManager` is even really returning the object `FSElogo.png`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the VS provided button with the `.BackgroundImage` property. Notice that the extension of the file is not included in the resource identifier. If this doesn't work, you will have to explain exactly how you added the resource to your project.

```
    MainButton.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.FSElogo
```

Comment: You are right, I wasn't adding the resource to the project properly, I was adding the file to the `Resources` folder and it seems like it wasn't the same as adding it to `resources.resx`
Once I added my file to `resources.resx`, I was able to use `My.Resources.FSElogo`

Comment: @AntoineCarpentier, you add your file on the Resources page and the IDE copies the file to that Resources folder. That folder is where resource source files are kept. Each time you build, the IDE looks for the file associated with each resource you have added in order to compile its contents into the final assembly. A file in that folder that is not associated with an added resource is simply ignored.