# visual studio 2019 how do I know what References to import and path settings

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, path, reference

I created a Visual Studio 2019 project that uses FileSystem.FileExists and both StreamWriter and StreamReader
I also created a folder named Resource with the intention of creating a txt file in this folder

Knowing I need to tell the Writer and Reader where to find the file I used these lines of code

```
Dim path As String = "C:/Users/Me/source/repos/TestForms/TestForms/Resource/"
If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt") Then
```

Because I do not full understand how to deal with a SQLite database yet lets say I put the database in the folder Resource. And if I make a EXE package that will run on another computer that string path is by my best guess is not going to work
In the process of leaning I keep seeing this line of code. I see no path to the database

```
m_dbConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;")
```

Granted I am dealing with a txt file now but if it was a SQLite database file
**My Question is how does the connection know where the database is ?**

I also need to import this reference Imports System.IO
Coming from NetBeans I got spoiled with Auto Import

**Second Question Does VS 2019 not have an Auto Import feature?**

I am adding a screen shot of Solution Explore
Tried to add Resource folder to Resources that did not work real well
[image]

Stream Reader Code below without error

```
    Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    readDATA()
End Sub

Private Sub readDATA()
    Dim line As String
    Using reader As New StreamReader(path & "Check.txt", True)
        line = reader.ReadToEnd.Trim
        tbHaveOne.Text = line
    End Using
End Sub
```

Code that creates Check.txt

```
    Private Sub frmThree_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    haveFILE()
    'tbHaveTwo.Text = frmOne.vR'KEEP see frmOne
    'tbHaveOne.Select()
End Sub

Public Sub haveFILE()
    'If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt") Then
    '    MsgBox("File found.")
    'Else
    '    MsgBox("File not found.")
    'End If
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt") Then
        ' Create or overwrite the file.
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path & "Check.txt")
        fs.Close()
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "File Created"
        tbHaveOne.Select()
    Else
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "File Found"
        tbHaveOne.Select()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pretty much never be hard-coding absolute paths. If you want to refer to a path under the program folder then you use `Application.StartupPath` as the root and a relative path, e.g.

```vb
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resource\Check.txt")
```

Then it doesn't matter where you run your program from. For other standard folder paths, you should use `Environment.GetFolderPath` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories`. For non-standard paths, you should let the user choose with a `FolderBrowserDialog`, `OpenFileDialog` or `SaveFileDialog` and then, if appropriate, save that path to a setting or the like.

When it comes to database connection strings, some ADO.NET providers support the use of *"|DataDirectory|"* in the path of a data file and that gets replaced at run time. What it gets replaced with depends on the type of app and how it was deployed. For Web Forms apps, it resolves to the *App_Data* folder. For ClickOnce Windows apps it resolves to a dedicated data folder. For other Windows apps, it resolves to the program folder, just like `Application.StartupPath`. I think the SQLite provider supports it but I'm not 100% sure. If it does, you could use something like this:

```vb
m_dbConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resource\MyDatabase.sqlite; Version=3;")
```

EDIT:

If you add data files to your project in the Solution Explorer and you want those to be part of the deployed application then you need to configure them to make that happen. Select the file in the Solution Explorer and then set the `Build Action` to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy Always` or, if you intend to make changes to the file when the app is running, `Copy if Newer`.

When you build, that file will then be copied from your project source folder to the output folder along with the EXE. You can then access it using `Application.StartupPath` at run time. That means while debugging as well as after deployment, because it will be copied to the "\bin\Release" output folder as well as the "\bin\Debug" output folder. If you add the file to a folder in the Solution Explorer, that file will be copied to, hence the reason I said earlier to use this:

```vb
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resource\Check.txt")
```

Comment: new error with this line of codeUsing reader As New StreamReader(filePath & "Check.txt", True) but not with same line ref writer ? Thanks for the response I did add your code ERROR IS BC30519

Comment: Application.StartupPath give this string C:\Users\Me\source\repos\PassVar\PassVar\bin\Debug NEED TO LOOSE the bin\Debug to get to Resource\Check.txt Any Idea ?

Comment: Application StartupPath generates this path which expects to find Resource Check.txt in the bin folder C:\Users\Me\source\repos\TestForms\TestForms\bin\Debug\Resource\Check.txt and when I put the Resource folder in the bin IT creates two Check.txt.Check.txt files ?

Comment: @Mary If you have a little free time Ted could use some help wit this question My last comment kind of explains what is not working as a result of changing the code to the answer

Comment: @Mary I looked at this but still lost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397657/replacing-absolute-file-path-by-resource-file-path/62398780#62398780

Comment: No, you don't need to lose the "\bin\Debug". Why do people make things so hard for themselves? Use your head. That "\bin\Debug" folder is where your EXE is. Of course that's the folder path you want. You can't possibly refer to the folder containing the project source files because that won't exist when you dep0loy the app. What you need to do is set the `Build Action` property of that file to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` and then it will be copied to that "\bin\Debug" folder each time you build, so the path will work as it should.

Comment: Sorry I am a little dense on this one I posted a screen shot that may explain what I am doing wrong Will delete the Resource folder I created and use your code I sill think I will get the BC30519 error with the read StreamReader code will post that code now below the screen shot

Comment: Based on that screenshot, the file isn't even part of your project. It looks like you created the folder in the Solution Explorer but then added the file in Windows Explorer. If you have to enable "Show All Files" to see it then that's definitely the case. Right-click on the "Check.txt" item and select "Include in Project". You can then configure it as I said and things will work the way they should. In future, add things to your project in the Solution Explorer. You can add a new text file first and then add the text or you can add an existing item from your Documents folder.

Comment: OK I will do the RIGHT CLICK and include in project I am also going to post the code that creates the Check.txt  If you look at it then I will delete Check.txt and test the idea of creating the Check.txt Thanks I did the include but the Check.txt did not move ?

Comment: OK, I didn't take into account that you were creating the file in code. In that case it should be part of your project and it DEFINITELY should not exist in that Resource folder in the project. STOP using that folder. Do what I said and use the Resource folder under the program folder. If that folder doesn't exist, create it using code too. Start doing what I've told you to do and it will work. Use `Application.StartupPath` and `Path.Combine`. I'm not going to post anything else until you stop ignoring that advice.

Comment: I deleted the folder as you instructed but I need to comment out the reader code it is showing ERROR BC30519 Will test the creating the Check.txt file OK it creates the FILE and I can write to it but NO READING ?? ODD it creates Check,txt Check.txttwice

Comment: Stop giving us an error code without an error message. Why do you think we should have to look that up?

Comment: BC30519 Visual Basic Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:   : Argument matching parameter 'stream' narrows from 'Object' to 'Stream'.   : Argument matching parameter 'path' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code to Create a Text file if it does not exist and if it does exist the user is notified.
We also were able to Write & Read from the Text file
One of the disappointments is we were not able to use StreamReader

We did solve this error where the file name was created like this "Check.txtCheck.txt
 This line of code below created the File this way in the folder Bin > Debug
If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath & "Check.txt") Then **See Code for correct format**

One other BIG lesson Do NOT create a folder and place your Text file in that folder
I am not sure using the code "Using" was a good idea further research needed on that issue

Working Code Below

```
    Private Sub frmThree_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    haveFILE()
End Sub

Public Sub haveFILE()
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(filePath).Dispose()
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "File Created"
        tbHaveOne.Select()
    Else
        My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) ' Then
        tbHaveTwo.Text = "File Found"
        tbHaveOne.Select()
    End If
    'This line of code created the File this was in the Bin > Debug folder Check.txtCheck.txt
    'If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath & "Check.txt") Then

End Sub
Sub PlaySystemSound()
    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand)
End Sub
Private Sub btnWrite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWrite.Click
    If tbHaveOne.Text = "" Then
        PlaySystemSound()
        'MsgBox("Please enter a username.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data")
        'If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        '    Return
        'End If
        Const Title As String = "To EXIT Click OK"
        Const Style = vbQuestion
        Const Msg As String = "Enter Data" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "Then Write Data"
        Dim result = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
        If result = vbOK Then
            'MsgBox("Enter Data")

            tbHaveOne.Select()
            Return
        End If
    End If
    writeDATA()
End Sub

Private Sub writeDATA()
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filePath, True)
    file.WriteLine(tbHaveOne.Text)
    file.Close()
    tbHaveOne.Clear()
    tbHaveTwo.Text = "Data Written"
End Sub

Private Sub btnRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    readDATA()
End Sub

Public Sub readDATA()
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath)
    tbHaveOne.Text = fileReader
End Sub
```